# Database structure for modelling one-way follower system like Twitter

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Would this be the ideal/most optimal way to implement a one-way 'following' relationship?

I have 2 tables as follows

Table1: User_Info_Table

```
UserID    Name   JoinDate
```

Table2: User_Follower_Table

```
FollowerID     FollowingID    Status
```

FollowerID and FollowingID are FK constraints to the User_Info_Table UserID column

The following logic takes place:

•User A follows User B

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM User_Follower_Table WHERE FollowerID = A and FollowingID = B and Status = 0)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO User_Follower_Table (FollowerID, FollowingID, Status)
    VALUES (A, B, 1)

END

ELSE

    UPDATE User_Follower_Table
    SET Status = 1
    WHERE FollowerID = A and FollowingID = B and Status = 0
```

•User A unfollows User B

```
UPDATE User_Follower_Table
SET Status = 0
WHERE FollowerID = A and FollowingID = B and Status = 1
```

•User B decides to follow User A back

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM User_Follower_Table WHERE FollowerID = B and FollowingID = A and Status = 0)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO User_Follower_Table (FollowerID, FollowingID, Status)
    VALUES (B, A, 1)

END

ELSE 

   UPDATE User_Follower_Table
   SET Status = 1
   WHERE FollowerID = B and FollowingID = A and Status = 0
```

•User B unfollows User A

```
UPDATE User_Follower_Table
SET Status = 0
WHERE FollowerID = B and FollowingID = A and Status = 1
```